# How to wrap html tags around each field in comment form?

Tags: php, html

I currently have an array which is part of a custom function for a comment form, but would like to wrap tags around each field for styling purposes. How would I achieve this? I have tried a few ways (echo etc..) which have thrown errors.

I currently have -

```
$fields = array(

    'author' =>
    '<p class="comment-form-author">' .
    '<input id="author" name="author" type="text" size="30" placeholder="' . __( 'Your Name (required)', 'pumba' ) . '" />' .
    '</p>',

    'email' =>
    '<p class="comment-form-email">' .
    '<input id="email" name="email" type="text" size="30" placeholder="' . __( 'Your Email (will not be published)', 'pumba' ) . '" />' .
    '</p>',

    'url' =>
    '<p class="comment-form-url">'  .
    '<input name="url" size="30" id="url" type="text" placeholder="' . __( 'Your Website (optional)', 'pumba' ) . '" />' .
    '</p>',

);
```

I would like to wrap each of the 3 fields (separately) in a -

```
<div class="c4">............</div>
```

Many thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There shouldn't be any problem doing this:

```
$fields = array(

    'author' =>
    '<div class="c4"><p class="comment-form-author">' .
    '<input id="author" name="author" type="text" size="30" placeholder="' . __( 'Your Name (required)', 'pumba' ) . '" />' .
    '</p></div>',

    'email' =>
    '<div class="c4"><p class="comment-form-email">' .
    '<input id="email" name="email" type="text" size="30" placeholder="' . __( 'Your Email (will not be published)', 'pumba' ) . '" />' .
    '</p></div>',

    'url' =>
    '<div class="c4"><p class="comment-form-url">'  .
    '<input name="url" size="30" id="url" type="text" placeholder="' . __( 'Your Website (optional)', 'pumba' ) . '" />' .
    '</p></div>',

);
```

Let me know if it works or not.

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
foreach($fields as $k => $v)
{
    $fields[$k] = '<div class="c4">'.$v.'</div>';
}
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can try with array_map:

```
$fields = array_map(
   function ($el) {
      return "<div class=\"c4\">{$el}</div>";
   },
   $fields
);
```

- [array_map](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-map.php)
- [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/de/functions.anonymous.php)